# when i run code in andriod studio in emulator this error message appears

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator, flutter-test

```
ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD
ERROR | is an experimental feature.
ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.
 INFO | Android emulator version 31.1.4.0 (build_id 7920983) (CL:N/A)
```

Comment: And have you started multiple emulators against the same AVD? If so, please don't do that.

Comment: Thanks Dear I got your point helpful for me.

Comment: So it works now? If so, I think you can just delete this question since it is not going to be that helpful for others since the core issue of the problem was actually being mentioned in the error dialog.

Comment: ok i deleted now